# Mobile headset audio OUT to MIC of another mobile using adapters

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, microphone, circuit-protection, headphones

I want give sound output of one android mobile to MIC of another android mobile using adapters only ( I can not build circuit).

One person suggested some work around using adapters , Please find below the handmade diagram based on suggestion. Can anyone please confirm whether it will work ? Because as per my understanding we can not feed sound output directly to MIC of another mobile due to level of sound.

**Please guide on the same or please suggest some sample or something better whatever is in your mind or YouTube video to achieve the same.**

Below adapters are used in this diagram as of now -

male TRRS to two female TRRS cable, male TRRS to Microphone and headset splitter, 3.5 mm mono to stereo adapter, 3.5 mm male to male TRS cable.

[image]

My target is to transcribe ( speech to text ) the voice of the caller on mobile1 to mobile2 using some speech to text software installed on mobile2. So If I will get call on my mobile1 then whatever caller will speak will be translated to text on mobile2( using some app installed on mobile2).

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. Do not create a duplicate question.

Comment: No- that question is half because original suggestor is not responding to my doubt. Now my focus is on how to achieve what i want using adapters only. If you have some better approach tell me @DaveTweed. I am doing this for entire needy community.

Comment: why are you focusing on a two device solution? ... perhaps the speech2text app could run on the same phone as the phone call ... headset would have to be used so that the user could look at the screen during a call

Comment: @Jsotola - Suppose you are calling on my mobile, how software(SpeechNote, Google live transcribe etc) on the same phone will catch your voice and will type on the same phone? To convert caller voice to text we need to feed that as imput to these app. In current case your voice which I am getting is in audio out not on mic in, thats why 2 phone solution is in picture. One phone solution is also there - please refer that youtube link --. https://youtu.be/7hb3p8LZIq8.    problem is - It supports english only and second issue is it process voice offline hence low accuracy. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: @jsotola - any input?